# Vectors as linear combinations

Tags: linear-algebra, combinations

I want to express **v**=$(\sqrt2,1/2)$ as linear combination of **p**=(1,2) and **q**=(2,1).

My answer:
$(\sqrt2,1/2)$=c(1,2)+d(2,1). So solve for c and d:

$\begin{pmatrix} \sqrt2 \\ 1/2 \end {pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 \\ 2 & 1 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} c \\ d\end{pmatrix}$

$\begin{pmatrix} c \\ d \end {pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} -\sqrt2/3 +1/3 \\ 2\sqrt2/3+1/6 \end{pmatrix}$

Is this right? It doesn't feel right for some reason.

Comment: This process is exactly right. It's just a matrix inverse, which is the usual thing to do when developing over a nonorthogonal basis. And of course you can always check the correctness by pluggint the solution back into the expression. It appears that something went wrong when you computed the inverse, $c(1,2)+d(2,1)=(\sqrt2,5/6)$. Maybe minus before $1/6$.

Comment: I have the same result as you, see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

We have
$$
\binom{c}{d}=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 \\ 2 & 1\end{pmatrix}^{-1}\binom{\sqrt{2}}{1/2}=\frac{1}{3}\begin{pmatrix} -1 & 2 \\ 2 & -1\end{pmatrix}\binom{\sqrt{2}}{1/2}=\frac{1}{3}\binom{1-\sqrt{2}}{(1-4\sqrt{2})/2}
$$

Comment: Thanks. When I sub c and d (using the correct answer), I can't get back to **v**=$(\sqrt2,1/2)$. Could someone please show me how to do this  in more detail? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The nice thing about (small) linear system is that, although solving it may involve some effort, checking the answer is fairly easy: just plug in, multiply and see if you get back the right hand side.